# swap positions list in scala

Tags: scala

I have an immutable list and I need to swap locations in it. Is there any easy way of doing it?

Below is my code:

```
def swap(i:Int, j:Int,li:List[T]):List[T]={
        if(i>=li.size && j >=li.size)
            throw new Error("invalie argument");

        val f = li(i)
        li(i) = li(j) //wont work
        li(j) = f;//wont work
        li;
    }
```

Initially, i tried it by converting it to an Array, changing the positions and then converting it to a List again. Any easy way?

Comment: The key bit here, and as you mentioned, is that the lists are immutable, so you can't swap the items.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An easy (but not very efficient way) of doing this would be

```
val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

l.updated(0,l(2)).updated(2,l(0))
res1: List[Int] = List(3, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 5):

you can only create a new list in `O(n)`. you may want to use a different data structure. you can do this by:

```
def swap[T](i:Int, j:Int,li:List[T]):List[T]={
    if(i>=li.size || j >=li.size || i >= j)
         throw new Error("invalid argument")

    li.dropRight(li.length - i) ::: (li(j) :: li.dropRight(li.length - j).drop(i+1)) ::: ((li(i) :: li.drop(j + 1)))
}
```

it's not very elegant, but it'll do the job. basically, i'm slicing the list on indexes `i` & `j`, so i have 5 parts: prefix of the list before `i`, `i`, the part between `i` & `j` exclusive, `j`, and the suffix of the list that comes after `j`. from there, it's simple concatenation with `i` & `j` swaped. it can be more efficient if you use list buffers, or even more efficient if you'll work on mutable `Array`s...

Answer (score 1):

One thing you may want to try (depending on the application, e.g. are you updating a point often etc...) is to use a 'Zipper', see below. You may want to add a 'moveTo' method, or similar. Potentially, you will have fewer updates, if dealing with immutable lists. I think the simple solution above is probably best for smallish lists.

Edit: probably could be tweaked if you know you are chasing elements near each other etc.

```
case class Zipper[A](focus: A, left: List[A], right: List[A]) {

  def fromZipper: List[A] = left ::: List(focus) ::: right

  /** Will throw NoSuchElementException if try to move beyond start. */

  /** directions are forward and backward across the list. */
  def moveForward: Zipper[A] = Zipper(right.head,left :+ focus,right.tail)
  def moveBackward: Zipper[A] = Zipper(left.last,left.init,focus :: right)

  /** Update the focus element. */
  def update(a: A): Zipper[A] = Zipper(a,left,right)
}


def apply[A](left: List[A], focus: A, right: List[A]): Zipper[A]
  = Zipper(focus,left,right)

def apply[A](xs: List[A]): Zipper[A]
    = Zipper(xs.head,List.empty[A],xs.tail)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is good way to do this but i how about something like this?

```
def swapElements(list: List[Any], first: Int, second: Int) = {
 def elementForIndex(index: Int, element: Any) = {
   if(index == first) {
     list(second)
   } else if(index == second){
     list(first)
   } else {
     element
   }
 }

 for(element <- ((0 to list.size - 1) zip list).to[List])
   yield elementForIndex(element._1, element._2)
}
```